# Lua stack overflow in recursive function in corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

For some reason the code below throws a stack overflow error if the else statement gets executed too many times. I am trying to have the scene.targeting function select a target from the `objTable` passed in the params, but only targets with a `.tgtFlag == false` are valid selections. If the function selects a target that has a `.tgtFlag == true`, it recalls the scene.targeting function passing in the same set of params.

The line that breaks is `local theTarget = params.objTable[math.random( 1, #params.objTable )]` but only after `else scene.targeting(params) end` is called several times.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function scene.targeting( params ) -- Targeting functions

  function animateTarget( target )
    if target.savedFlag == false then
      transition.to( target, {time = 100, y = target.y - 15} )
      transition.to( target, {time = 100, delay = 150, y = target.y, onComplete = animateTarget}     )
    end
  end

  local theTarget = params.objTable[math.random( 1, #params.objTable )]
  if theTarget.tgtFlag == false then
    theTarget.tgtFlag = true
    animateTarget(theTarget)
  else
    scene.targeting(params)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to [*Programming in Lua*](http://www.lua.org/pil/6.3.html):

> A tail call is a kind of goto dressed as a call. A tail call happens when a function calls another as its last action, so it has nothing else to do.

In your example, `animateTarget` obviously isn't called in such a way, and can and will suffer from stack overflows. Either rewrite it to make use of TCO or change it to non-recursive version.

Comment: I didn't know about tail calls. Great little trick to not use the stack.